# How to avoid parallel execution of the same file By different workflow/state machine in stepfunction?

Tags: aws-step-functions

for example, I don't want to process fileA by workflow1 and workflow2 at the same time. If any of the workflows is processing for fileA, the rest should wait for the current workflow to complete?
Please note I am passing file id from SQS queue to trigger the workflow
And also I don't want to leverage dynamoDB for this

I tried looking for solutions to store the file id that is being processed by step function, but couldn't find anything other than having a db to store the file ids

Comment: So you want a file that starts #1 to continue to #2 only after #1 finishes?  In other words, run the workflows sequentially, #1 then #2, not in parallel?

Comment: Yes. two workflows should not run parallely for the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Chain the two workflows together: Queue -> Workflow 1 -> Workflow 2.

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-nested-workflows.html): AWS Step Functions can start workflow executions directly from a Task state of a state machine. This allows you to break your workflows into smaller state machines, and to start executions of these other state machines.